# Path with maximum average value

Tags: java, matrix

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class maxAvgPath {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] c = new int[n+1][n+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                c[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
   float sum = c[0][0];
   float m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if (c[i][j + 1] < c[i + 1][j]) {
                    sum = sum + c[i + 1][j];
                    m++;
                    

                } else {
                    sum = sum + c[i][j + 1];
                    m++;
                    
                }
        }
    }

    System.out.println((sum/m));
}
}
```

Given a square matrix of size N*N, where each cell is associated with a specific cost. A path is defined as a specific sequence of cells which starts from the top-left cell move only right or down and ends on bottom right cell. We want to find a path with the maximum average over all existing paths. Average is computed as total cost divided by the number of cells visited in the path.
Input : Matrix = [1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9]
Output : 5.8
Path with maximum average is, 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9
Sum of the path is 29 and average is 29/5 = 5.8

But I am not getting the correct output can some tell where is my mistake?

Comment: Who is "we"? Did your for get to re-phrase your assignment?

Comment: what thats mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your m should always be `2 * n - 1`. Regardless of the chosen path, you will always move either right or down, starting from top-left corner. You have n - 1 rows and n - 1 columns, so you're moving right exactly n - 1 and moving down exactly n - 1 times. In total, counting the top-left, you have 1 + (n - 1) + (n - 1) numbers on your ideal path. Therefore, you're not looking for a max average, you're actually looking for a maximum sum.

Your loops are not exactly in sync with what you're trying to do. Let's say, for the given matrix, when `i = 0, j is 0`, that you discover that 4 is bigger than 2. You pick the 4, `m[1][0]`, and then you should check the max of m[1][1] and m[2][0] ... but your loop moves to ... i = 0, j = 1, allowing you to check m[1][2] and m[1][1].

You're also using a Greedy aproach which won't always give you the best result, e.g. [1 2 9, 3 4 9, 5 2 9], your algorithm will pick 1, move down to 3 and 5 then right to 2 and 9, giving you a total of 20. However, the ideal path is 1, right to 2 and 9, then down to 9 and 9, for a grand total of 30.

One approach to solve this is to keep the loops, but instead of maintaining one sum, you need to keep track of multiple sums and picking a max at every step.

e.g. for [1 2 9, 3 4 9, 5 2 9], you initialize your sum matrix with `0` and start navigating.

For sum[0][0], there is only one possible sum, which is picking up m[0][0]. This continues for the entire 1st row, so your sum matrix is now [1 3 12, 0 0 0, 0 0 0]. For sum[1][0], there is also only one possible sum, moving down from m[0][0], so sum[1][0] is m[0][0] + m[1][0]. And here the fun starts.

For sum[1][1], you need to pick between sum[0][1] and sum[1][0] and add m[1][1]. You will of course pick sum[1][0] (which is really m[0][0] + m[1][0]) and add m[1][1] to it, so sum[1][1] is 8. Therefore, if your maximal path ever travels to r1c1, you know that you've picked the maximum possible sum so far.

I will also highlight the next step, sum[1][2], where you have to pick between sum[0][2] and sum[1][1] and add m[1][2]. We know sum[0][2] is 12, sum[1][1] is 8, so, if our path ever reaches cell r1c2, we know that we need to pick first row entirely and then move down instead(m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][2], m[1][2]) of moving down and picking the next row (m[0][0], m[1][0], m[1][1], m[1][2]), so your current maximal sum in sum[1][2] is 21 and your sum matrix is [1 3 12, 4 8 21, 0 0 0].

Final row is the same thing:

```
sum[2][0] = sum[1][0] + m[2][0]
sum[2][1] = max(sum[1][1], sum[2][0]) + m[2][1]
sum[2][2] = max(sum[1][2], sum[2][1]) + m[2][2]
```

Your sum matrix eventually becomes [ 1 3 12, 4 8 21, 9 11 30 ], therefore your
max is 30. You have picked up 2 * 3 - 1 = 5 numbers, so your average is 6.

Illustrating the sum matrix is also interesting:

```
1  3 12
4  8 21
9 11 30
```

If you ever want to determine what was the path you've chosen from top-left to bottom-right, you just need to follow the sums, in descending order(keeping in mind the move-right or move-down rule), 30 -> 21 -> 12 -> 3 -> 1.

I will leave the coding part as an exercise, you have all the details you need.

(sorry for bad formatting and long text)